# Big number and lost of precision

Tags: dart

I do this operation and I want result without exponents :

```dart
main(){
  var result = ((1.1+2)+3.14+4+(5+6+7)+(8+9+10)*4267387833344334647677634)/2*553344300034334349999000;
  print(result); // With exponent
  print(result.toInt()); // Full number ?
}
```

And it print

```dart
3.18780189038289e+49
31878018903828901761984975061078744643351263313920
```

But the `toInt()` result is wrong, the good result is 31878018903828899277492024491376690701584023926880 . It check it with groovy (web) console.
How can I do to have my int full number ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in `result` there are `double` literals, the `result` type is `double`.

In Dart a `double` is a :

> 64-bit (double-precision) floating-point numbers, as specified by the IEEE 754 standard

This is why you lose precision.

You can see the lost of precision with the following code :

```dart
final bignum = 31878018903828899277492024491376690701584023926880;
print(bignum);
// displays 31878018903828899277492024491376690701584023926880
print(bignum.toDouble().toInt());
// displays 31878018903828901761984975061078744643351263313920
```

This lost of precision is not specific to Dart, for instance `31878018903828899277492024491376690701584023926880.0` and `31878018903828901761984975061078744643351263313920.0` are equal in Java.

The groovy web console gives you the right result because AFAICT [groovy literals with decimal points are instantiated as java.math.BigDecimal by default](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math).

Finally there is [an open issue on Decimal data type](http://dartbug.com/681) you can star and until decimals are natively supported, you can use my [decimal package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/decimal);